# LNK 2038 error after upgrading to visual studio 2015

Tags: c++, hyperlink, visual-studio-2015

i was working on a project in visual studio 2013 , then i upgraded to visual studio 2015 . the project was ok on earlier version but now i get these errors :

```
1>sfml-system-s-d.lib(String.cpp.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1800' doesn't match value '1900' in Aircraft.obj
1>sfml-graphics-s-d.lib(VertexArray.cpp.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol ??0_Container_base12@std@@QAE@XZ (public: __thiscall std::_Container_base12::_Container_base12(void)) imported
1>sfml-system-s-d.lib(String.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::bad_cast::bad_cast(char const *)" (__imp_??0bad_cast@std@@QAE@PBD@Z) referenced in function "class std::ctype<wchar_t> const & __cdecl std::use_facet<class std::ctype<wchar_t> >(class std::locale const &)" (??$use_facet@V?$ctype@_W@std@@@std@@YAABV?$ctype@_W@0@ABVlocale@0@@Z)
1>sfml-graphics-s-d.lib(Shader.cpp.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::bad_cast::bad_cast(char const *)" (__imp_??0bad_cast@std@@QAE@PBD@Z)
```

there are too many of them , but i just included one of each . 
i found similar questions , but none of them worked for me . i am using SFML library . 
steps i've done to solve the problem are : 
downloading sfml for vc14 . 
rebuild sloution . 
try to ignore _MSC_VER in preprocessor commands(there were no 2038 errors any more , but still i had other link errors) .

no success ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mismatch among version of Visual Studio used for libraries and project which you are try to compile. Some of them are compiled with Visual Studio 2013 while you're building the project with Visual Studio 2015.

If you want to use Visual Studio 2015 to compile your project, you must compile all the required libraries (e.g. SFML) with Visual Studio 2015 (or, in alternative, find pre-built libraries with VS2015 if available).

Comment: i have downloaded the vc14 sfml version , i put it where the previous sfml version was ! i don't know why it does not working ... i am using static version of library , do you think it is the problem? on the previous visual studio i created a template sloution , where i had all the options set for using sfml , and then i just upgraded it ...

Comment: The error said that sfml-system-s-d.lib was compiled with version _MSC_VER == 1800  of VIsual Studio which is Visual Studio 2013. Can you check if it is taking the correct library in the linker properties of the project in Visual Studio?

Comment: if you mean additional directory , yes it is set to the correct path also input is correct ( no change from previous version have been made)

Comment: The version of SFML you need is provided as pre-built binaries on this page: https://nightlybuilds.ch/project/show/1/SFML/ (VS2015). Check if you are compiling 32 or 64 bit and then choose the correct version.

Comment: just downloaded from the site you provided , still same errors !

Comment: Which version: x32 or x64? Is it the same of your configuration build? When you change libraries use rebuild and not build.

Comment: I tried both , no change , and yes i used rebuild ... The template itself works ! I wrote the sfml test code , and it is working ! Only this one do not work ...

Comment: The only reason of this error is that it is finding a wrong library compiled with another VS version. Try to move the VS2013 version in another directory or to remove it from your PC temporarily.

Comment: I dont have visual studio 2013 on my pc ... I dont know why i get this error , try to make another template ...

Comment: No, I was suggesting to delete version of SFML compiled with VS2013 from your PC (not Visual Studio) or SFML at all and then reinstall only the version compiled with VS2015.